# Java Reflection on unknown Generic

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection

I'm playing for learning purposes with Javas Generics and try to use Reflection on them. 
In the same moment I thoght I understand the half of it, I'm running into problems I didn't see a way to solve. 
I have a simple Box class:

```
public class ReflectionBox<E>  {
    protected E e;

    public ReflectionBox(){}
    public ReflectionBox(E element){ this.e = element; }

    public void set(E element){ e = element; }
    public E get(){ return e; }
    //... a few reflection methods...
}
```

I extended this Class to try to implement an Interface with it. This Interface forces me to write an statement like this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableBox<?>> CREATOR = 
        new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableBox<?>>() {
    @Override
    public ParcelableBox<?> createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ParcelableBox<Object>(source);
    }
}
```

Is it Possible to get Class informations from `?` using Reflection? I cannot use methods from `Object` on it to reflect which Class is put inside, neither instanciate a `new ParcelableBox<?>(? element)`.The Parcel isn't the Class which E should be, but my Class is 
IN that Parcel and should be the Class of `?`.

---

EDIT: 
Hi, thanks for all the answers: As many User don't understand, what I'm trying to do:
There is an Interface `Parcelable`,which I think it works as a Data Stream, in which You can put Object members. You Use something like `parcel.writeString(String string)` or  `parcel.writeValue(Object value)` to store and `parcel.readValue` in the same direction as you put it inside. For learning I wanna implement this into a generic. So I wanna be able to store to Parcel, and read from it using Reflection.
because CREATOR is static I cannot use E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is impossible. Generics are also called "erasures" because they are removed from the class during compilation. Generics are compile time feature that does not exist at runtime, so there is not way to retrieve this information.

But there is a workaroud. Create special field `Class<?> type;` and put there the type yo wish to retrieve. Then just retrieve it.

BTW you already have almost this solution. You have a field `protected E e;`. So, you can use `e.getClass()` to determine the type.

Comment: @AlexR can you be more specific with the "workaround"? I can't get it to work cuz i get the same mistake as Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the type of `E` is going to be `Parcel` for the `CREATOR` instance you can just write it as:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableBox<Parcel>> CREATOR = 
        new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableBox<Parcel>>() {
    @Override
    public ParcelableBox<Parcel> createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ParcelableBox<Parcel>(source);
    }
}
```

So no reflection would be necessary. Although it really depends on what you are trying to do. I wasn't able to figure it out completely from you small example.

If you really need to use reflection then it will be difficult, because generic information is not stored at runtime, so you cannot do things like `obj instanceof E`. All you can do is `obj.getClass()` which might be quite limiting.

Comment: no, `Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableBox<Parcel>>()` is exactly what I want to avoid, because Parcel has stored an Object of E, which i put into using Reflection on an instance of E.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code to generify DAO implementation for hibernate based code and it helped when you don't pass the 'T' object to constructor.

```
public class Dao<T> {    
private Class<T> type;

    public Dao() {
        if (getClass().getGenericSuperclass() instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
                    .getGenericSuperclass();
            this.type = (Class<T>) (parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        }
    }

    public T findByPrimaryKey(Serializable key) {
        return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(type, key);
    }
}
```

From your example and description, it is not clear what is needed; it will help me to reply better if the example is clear.